# How to create a persistent html5 audio player?

Tags: javascript, django, html5-audio, http-live-streaming

I have the following code to open a player on my website for audio playback
using Django:

```
{% if track.file.hls_stream %}
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'stream' pk=track.file.pk|safe|cypher_link_stream %}" target="_blank"><i class="fad fa-play-circle"></i></a>
...
```

Currently this opens a new tab and uses VideoJS to play the HLS stream. But actually this is not what I want. I would like to hit the play button, and a audio player pop's up at the bottom of the page and stays there while navigating on the site. I already searched for such a solution but didn't had that much luck. Can someone maybe give me a hint where to look at?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to say without knowing a bit more about your tech stack. However, off the top of my head, I feel the most common approach with this kind of problem is to build the site as a SPA (Single Page Application) using one of the popular frontend frameworks like React, Vue, or Angular.

By building a SPA, you can navigate between page routes "virtually", where new data can be retrieved and mounted to the DOM while having other unchanged elements (like your music player) persist between changes.

To accomplish this with Vue, you would use  to move between pages without refreshing. See [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/) for details

Comment: First of thanks for your interest in my question. Actually large parts of the application are already done and implementing some JS framework without even having big knowledge onto JS it seems a bit overkill. Beside, we only need it for this one single thing. Is there maybe another solution? Would be awesome if there would be some kind of layer thing i can do with html, keep one layer and reload the other or so... Just to implement such a navigation concept.

Comment: My pleasure. The challenge you have is that when the user navigates between pages, a "refresh" will occur on the page unless you "fake" the page route changes (as in the case of the SPA). Unfortunately, this will require pretty structural changes for your purposes.

The only other workaround that comes to mind is to use a popup; however, you can "fake" this banner kind of effect  by modifying the popup size and pos though there may be some big drawbacks:

`window.open('yourpage.htm','pagename','resizable,height={H},width={W}, top={TOP_RELATIVE_TO_WINDOW}, left={LEFT_RELATIVE_TO_WINDOW}')`

Comment: Okay lets simply assume I want to use this from VideoJS. How can I implement it?
https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-audio-tracks.html
Currently im trying to add a track to the playlist and than play the playlist but not sure how this works

Comment: I'm not sure if I can direct you generally on how to use VideoJS; however, one quirk for your use-case will be to pass data between your parent window and the popup (in this case containing the audio data, or src/metadata for it) .. Here, you will likely have to use:
`window.postMessage()`

See details here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

I hope I've managed to answer your question -  that is, to give you a hint on where to look. Best of luck

Comment: I already opened another question onto this, please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299706/how-to-use-videjs-audiotracks-api

and thanks again ;)